# What are the benefits of this command line (/usr/bin/awk '{$1=$1};1') instead of pure cat

Tags: bash, awk, scripting, cat, aws

I am reading the AWS [`eic_harvest_hostkeys`](https://github.com/aws/aws-ec2-instance-connect-config/blob/master/src/bin/eic_harvest_hostkeys) script and I don't understand this line:

```
key=$(/usr/bin/awk '{$1=$1};1' < "${file}")
```

What is the of benefit awk?
Isn't `key=$(/bin/cat "${file}")` better?

Comment: See: [How do I trim leading and trailing whitespace from each line of some output?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/102008)

Comment: It's not that there's a **benefit** of one over  the other, they just do different things.

Comment: Use of cat: `key=$(< "${file}")` does the same thing as `key=$(/bin/cat "${file}")`

Comment: It seems a bit *awk*ward.

Comment: @Wastrel not quite. When `file=-x`, i.e. it's referencing a filename that begins with a dash, the `key=$(<"$file")` works correctly whereas `key=$(cat "$file")` will produce an error such as `cat: unknown option -- x` with many (all?) implementations of `cat`

Comment: @roaima Ah, so that's why I don't use cat!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The assignment to `$1` forces `awk` to rewrite the input line to a canonical format.

```
{ echo 'one  two  three'; echo '  indented with trailing  '; } | cat
one  two  three
  indented with trailing

{ echo 'one  two  three'; echo '  indented with trailing  '; } | awk '{$1=$1}; 1'
one two three
indented with trailing
```

Furthermore, when `file=-x`, i.e. it's referencing a filename that begins with a dash, using `key=$(<"$file")` will work correctly whereas `key=$(cat "$file")` will produce an error such as `cat: unknown option -- x` with many (all?) implementations of `cat`.

Comment: Note that the `;` in between `{$1=$1}` and `1` which (contrary  to the OP) you omitted is required in the standard `awk` syntax (a newline would also do), though in practice, it's not needed in any `awk` implementations that I know (still, the maintainer of gawk objected to relaxing that requirement in the standard).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you. I wasn't aware of the `;` being required by the standard

Answer (score 17):

`key=$(/bin/cat "${file}")` sets `key` to the content of the file¹, without its trailing newlines. (I'm assuming a text file, without null bytes.)

`key=$(/usr/bin/awk '{$1=$1};1' < "${file}")` normalizes horizontal whitespace: it removes spaces and tabs at the beginning and at the end of each line, and it compressed internal sequences of spaces and tabs to a single space. While `$1=$1` looks like a no-op, it actually causes awk to rebuild the line based on the updated field, and rebuilding the line erases the information of exactly what whitespace was around fields. It then also removes trailing newlines.

---

<sup>¹ assuming `$file` doesn't start with a `-` which would cause `cat` to treat it as an option argument. Using `key=$(cat < "$file")` would be better (`key=$(cat -- "$file")` would also be an improvement but `file='-'` would still be a problem).</sup>

Comment: @Wastrel - tell that to the asker.  Gilles is just explaining what was presented in the question.

Comment: @Toby: Ah, quite so. Well, then..

Comment: The `cat` version does not strip or convert newlines.  Of course, that goes along with the general thrust of this answer, that the `awk` version modifies data passing through, whereas the `cat` version does not.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The command substitution strips trailing newlines. Both commands preserve other newlines.

Answer (score 0):

even that's too verbose already. just do :

```
[m/n/g]awk NF=NF
```

don't even need any quotation at shell level,
since the first `NF` on left side prevents the shell from attempting to do anything with that equal `=` sign